# Facebook Graph API: Retrieve feed with comments & likes for individual posts in one API call in Java

Tags: facebook-graph-api, comments, feed, rate-limiting

Is there a way to retrieve all facebook posts in the feed with their comments & likes in one API call?

Currently I have to make an API call to retrieve the feed and for each idividual post one more API call to get its comment and like counts. Due to this I always exceed rate limit!

I found this: [Facebook graph API to fetch facebook feeds with comment count and like count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20471327/facebook-graph-api-to-fetch-facebook-feeds-with-comment-count-and-like-count) 
but unfortunately FQL is not longer available, so I try to find another solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you need only comments and likes counts, you can use something like this:

```
me/posts?fields=likes.limit(0).summary(true),comments.limit(0).summary(true)
```

Comment: Hello, Could you help me or give a hint on how to get likes and shared from post from between a date with the user's name and id?

Comment: if you need to restrict the search between two dates, you must add the dates at the end of url ```&until=2018-11-22&since=2018-11-10``` for shared info i don't know. Maybe look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9728279/getting-the-facebook-like-share-count-for-a-given-url/39379251#39379251) and [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.2/object/sharedposts)